# Outlook Calendar input field DOM manipulation from Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm building an Chrome Extension for Outlook Calendar - https://outlook.live.com/calendar/

What I'm trying to do is that when user clicks somewhere on calendar, and default new event creation popup shows up, the title of this event is filled by Chrome Extension.

So, I identify this input field with this CSS selector and I set its value to something:

```
document.querySelector('input[aria-label="Add details for the event"]').value = 'test123';
```

The UI is updated to test123, but if I click somewhere else on the page the value reverts to default one, or if I just save the event, it won't save it with this value I set through chrome extension.

You can try this from the console, no need to install chrome extension.

I guess this input field somehow relies on an frontend framework and its binding, but I can't figure it out... Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

adding this after setting input's value solves it:

```
document.querySelector('input[aria-label="Add details for the event"]').dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }));
```